# Cloud Functions for Firebase: "TypeError: DialogflowApp is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Trying to use actions-on-google to get the user's position, but I can't seem to even make this work, any help?

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DialogflowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogflowApp;

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => 
{
    const app = new DialogflowApp({request, response});
    ...
}
```

TypeError: DialogflowApp is not a constructor
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest

Comment: What version of the actions-on-google library are you using?

Comment: Just tested this code and is working correctly, `actions-on-google@1.10.0`

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem within the package.json file. You have to include the right versions. For me works:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ajv-keywords": "^2.1.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.2",
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase": "^2.4.2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. I used firebase CLI to create and build my project and I solved this problem deleting the "**lib**" folder that was automatically generated inside the **functions** folder and I built the project again.

I also added this code to package JSON:

```
"build": "rm -rf lib/ && tsc",
```